# "Author et al., submitted", is that possible with \citep?

Tags: packages, citing, natbib, package-options, cite-package

Is it possible to have "Author et al., submitted" using the package natbib? e.g.:

```
@article{papersubmitted,
    title = {{I love LaTeX, and you?}},
    author = {Author1, Name and Author2, Name and Author3, Name},
    note = {submitted}
}
```

so, using:

```
\citep{papersubmitted}
```

gives:

```
Author1 et al., [n.d]
```

but I need:

```
Author1 et al., submitted
```

I tried 'submitted' in year but it gave some error messages that afaik relate to integers.

Thanks in advance for any hint,

PS. I am using report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{papersubmitted,
    title = {{I love LaTeX, and you?}},
    author = {Author1, Name and Author2, Name and Author3, Name},
    year = {submitted},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{papersubmitted}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to keep the example selfcontained; use your own file in the argument to `\bibliography`.

[image]